# sending and receiving emails from gmail with sdk android

Tags: android, email, sdk, smtp, jakarta-mail

I'm been following this link [Sending Email in Android using JavaMail API without using the default/built-in app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2020088/sending-email-in-android-using-javamail-api-without-using-the-default-android-app/2033124#2033124), but it doesn't work for me, that code throw an exception, and if I do a try..catch, it doesn't catch anything. There is anyone that have tried that code and worked for them? Could you upload a working code for test? When I track the code, the error is after the creation of the DataHandler, I don't know why.
I Add external libs, mail, activation, additional, and doesn't work, i don't know what is my problem.

Comment: in catch add e.printtracktrace()...and which error occure??

Comment: in the catch i make Log.e( tag, e.getMessage());  and this dont catch anything, the error where only i see is in the app that say, that Sorry, that application stopped...etc

Comment: add your code.........and check on device also...........

Comment: String Body = "This is the Body of my email";
new DataHandler(new ByteArrayDataSource(body.getBytes(), "text/plain")); send a execption. and my ByteArrayDataSource is like the link the i put...

Comment: in that link i see that a lot of peaple says that run ok, i just un source code of somebody its run, where i can see, if the problem consiste i think that i need update somethig...

Comment: Are you running this on a phone or on an emulator?

Comment: on emulator and in the phone... both

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found other way to receive emails from gmail or any other email provider.

```
     Properties props = new Properties();
    //IMAPS protocol
    props.setProperty("mail.store.protocol", "imaps");
    //Set host address
    props.setProperty("mail.imaps.host", "imaps.gmail.com");
    //Set specified port
    props.setProperty("mail.imaps.port", "993");
    //Using SSL
    props.setProperty("mail.imaps.socketFactory.class", "javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory");
    props.setProperty("mail.imaps.socketFactory.fallback", "false");
    Session imapSession = Session.getInstance(props);
    Store store = imapSession.getStore("imaps");
    store.connect("imap.gmail.com", usr, password);
Folder inbox = store.getFolder("Inbox");
inbox.open(Folder.READ_WRITE);
    Message[] msgs =inbox.getMessages()
```